# MVC Unobtrusive validating not working properly

Tags: model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

I have already configured unobtrusive and jquery-val to validate client-side, when I click on submit button the validate verify the fields and return the propers messages from the model, after that the aplication hint the controller action ignoring the jquery-val and submit the form.

So, the validation works but still submitting.
I have already checked the correctly scripts:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

And the configuration on web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Also my model there are the proper validation notation and in my view I use

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

What I'm doing wrong?
thanks!

Comment: Are you calling validate on client side before submitting form or is it DataAnnotations causing this?

Comment: I'm using just DataAnnotation. The strange is the app calls de validation and submit action almost together,  but the validation 1 second before the submit.